# Speeding up JSON parsing in Go

Tags: json, performance, go

We have transaction log files in which each transaction is a single line in JSON format.  We often need to take selected parts of the data, perform a single time conversion, and feed results into another system in a specific format.  I wrote a Python script that does this as we need, but I hoped that Go would be faster, and would give me a chance to start learning Go.  So, I wrote the following:

```
package main
import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"
import "time"
import "bufio"
import "os"

func main() {

    sep := ","

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        data, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        byt := []byte(data)

        var dat map[string]interface{}

        if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
            break
        }

        status := dat["status"].(string)
        a_status := dat["a_status"].(string)
        method := dat["method"].(string)
        path := dat["path"].(string)
        element_uid := dat["element_uid"].(string)
        time_local := dat["time_local"].(string)
        etime, _ := time.Parse("[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]", time_local)
        fmt.Print(status, sep, a_status, sep, method, sep, path, sep, element_uid, sep, etime.Unix(), "\n")
    }
}
```

That compiles without complaint, but I'm surprised at the lack of performance improvement.  To test, I placed 2,000,000 lines of logs into a tmpfs (to ensure that disk I/O would not be a limitation) and compared the two versions of the script.  My results:

```
$ time cat /mnt/ramdisk/logfile | ./stdin_conv > /dev/null 
real    0m51.995s

$ time cat /mnt/ramdisk/logfile | ./stdin_conv.py > /dev/null 
real    0m52.471s

$ time cat /mnt/ramdisk/logfile > /dev/null 
real    0m0.149s
```

How can this be made faster?  I have made some rudimentary efforts.  The ffjson project, for example, proposes to create static functions that make reflection unnecessary; however, I have failed so far to get it to work, getting the error:

```
Error: Go Run Failed for: /tmp/ffjson-inception810284909.go
STDOUT:

STDERR:
/tmp/ffjson-inception810284909.go:9:2: import "json_parse" is a program, not an importable package

:
```

Besides, wouldn't what I have above be considered statically typed?  Possibly not-- I am positively dripping behind the ears where Go is concerned.  I have tried selectively disabling different attributes in the Go code to see if one is especially problematic.  None have had an appreciable effect on performance.  Any suggestions on improving performance, or is this simply a case where compiled languages have no substantial benefit over others?

Comment: python's json library is mostly optimized C. These *should* be around the same speed to start with (that's not to say there couldn't be other optimizations, I haven't looked)

Comment: I haven't done a side by side to compare but I'd be surprised if unmarshalling into a struct wouldn't improve performance. I mean, why are you deserializing into a map just so that you can explicitly assign every value while having to specify the type?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal's comment is probably the only big change you can easily make to this code, use a struct with proper tags. Next step would be to make a json.Unmarshaler to avoid the reflection (and could do the etime parsing for you at the same time). If you want ffjson to do this for you, that's another question.

Comment: You can also add paralelisim to gain more speed. For example creating for workers, one per CPU and read part of the file, for lines 500 to 1000 etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a type to remove all this unnecessary assignment and type assertion;

```
type RenameMe struct {
     Status string `json:"status"`
     Astatus string `json:"a_status"`
     Method string `json:"method"`
     Path string `json:"path"`
     ElementUid string `json:"element_uid"`
     TimeLocal time.Time `json:"time_local"`
     Etime time.Time // deal with this after the fact
}

data := &RenameMe{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, data); err != nil {
            break
        }

data.Etime,  _ := time.Parse("[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]", time_local)
```

I'm not going to test this to ensure it outperforms your code but I bet it does by a large margin. Give it a try and let me know please.

Comment: I will post how it works.  I'm trying now to integrate it into my code.  It's a long process... I'm very new at this, and I'd like to do it without asking questions.  Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew: I had a minute to test (during a long, non-go related build ;) ), and this will give you the best improvement (I got 36% faster). If you want to try and squeeze another 10% or so, you can give ffjson a try, but there's not a huge gain with a small, simple repeating structure like this.

Comment: Nice!  
`$ time cat /mnt/ramdisk/logfile | ./stdin_conv_typed > /dev/null 
real 0m37.862s`.  Thank you very much.  Sorry for taking so long, but it's been educational.

Comment: @Andrew np! Thanks for the confirmation. Ideally I would test it anyway but I'm not working in Go currently so it would have been fairly time consuming for me to get things set up.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsoniter.com/ declares itself to be the fastest json parser, golang and java implementations are provided. Two types of api can be used. And pre-injected json object definition is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/pquerna/ffjson

I saw 3x improvements over the standard json marshal/unmarshal method employed by the standard lib. It does so by rewrite the source and removing the need for reflection.